# mongoose required true req.body.name {}

Tags: node.js, express

If I set required to false, it will successfully create an object in the MongoDB database with one id. I suffer confusion sometimes, check my profile if you want. I think it's a little thing. If you need more info, just comment.

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var product = require('./routes/product'); // Imports routes for the products
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); // Set up mongoose connection

var dev_db_url = 'mongodb://localhost/Product';
var mongoDB = process.env.MONGODB_URI || dev_db_url;
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use('/products', product);


var port = 3002;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server is up on port numbner ' + port);
});
```

model.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ProductSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true, max: 100},
    price: {type: Number, required: true},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

controller.js

```
var Product = require('../models/product');

//Simple version, without validation or sanitation
exports.test = function (req, res) {
    res.send('Greetings from the Test controller!');
};

exports.product_create = function (req, res, next) {
    var product = new Product(
        {
            name: req.body.name,
            bags: req.body.bags
        }
    );
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))
    product.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        res.send('Bags Created successfully')
    })
};
```

router.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// Require the controllers WHICH WE DID NOT CREATE YET!!
var product_controller = require('../controllers/product');

// a simple test url to check that all of our files are communicating correctly.
router.get('/test', product_controller.test);


router.post('/create', product_controller.product_create);

module.exports = router;
```

HTTP POST: http://localhost:3002/products/create?name=Jorge&price=20

> ValidationError: Product validation failed: name: Path `name` is
>   required

Can you help?
Thanks!

Comment: How do you creating and saving the Product object?

Comment: @MaulikSakhida product.save(function .. controller. Am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it's error, because your `req.body.name` is empty or null. Why it's null or empty or undefined? Because you're not add your `data` in your body, when you send create request.

You can see your **Endpoint:**

HTTP POST: http://localhost:3002/products/create?name=Jorge&price=20

It's not about `req.body`, it's a `req.params`. So you can use `req.params.name` and `req.params.price`.

️‍♂️ So, **If you're passing your data using parameres**, your `code` will looks like this:

```js
exports.product_create = function (req, res, next) {
    var product = new Product(
        {
            name: req.params.name,
            price: req.params.price
        }
    );
    console.log(req.params);
    product.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        res.send('Bags Created successfully')
    })
};
```

If you want to use `req.body`, than add your `json` object to`body` if you're using Postman.

️‍♂️ You can see the image below: **An example using postman to passing your data into body**, before you send `create` request to your backend.

[image]

So, **If You're passing your data from body**, than your `code` will looks like this:

```js
exports.product_create = function (req, res, next) {
    var product = new Product(
        {
            name: req.body.name,
            price: req.body.price
        }
    );
    console.log(req.body);
    product.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        res.send('Bags Created successfully')
    })
};
```

I hope it's can help you.

Comment: What else did you change? I am getting {} from your console.log. ValidationError: Product validation failed: name: Path `name` is required. Same for the second parameter.

Comment: From an example Above, I am using data name and price, that's why I change `req.body.bags` from yours to 'req.body.price`.

Comment: Both of them are {}.. How can you GET from postman and receive values? No matter I POST always same result

Comment: Sure, you will get the result {}, if you are wrong in `console.log(req.params)` and `console.log(req.body)`. Make sure you are not wrong to do it, because what I wrote above I have tried first and I get the results as expected.

Comment: I have done this sort of API and use of Postman before and working, but this time is not working either with req.body or req.params.. I quit now and accept your answer anyway. Thanks for input

Comment: Your code I've been try and I've been edited it. You can get your example code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-williamson-hmf3g. That's code it's working fine.